# Can we poll for notification from service worker

Tags: push-notification, service-worker

When implementing push notifications using service worker, we can directly push the notifications to the endpoint. But in my website the notifications are fetched from an outside API. So Is there any way from my service worker to poll for notifications so that I can identify if a new notification is present?

Answer (score 3):

If your web application is open, you can show notifications by checking for some criteria (polling an API, etc.) and then using the [Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API).

This does not require a service worker. Using a service worker + `push` events to trigger your notifications means that your notifications will appear even if your web application is closed, and it also is more efficient to rely on listening for `push` events vs. repeatedly polling an API.

You could theoretically use a combination of polling and explicitly calling the Notifications API when your web app is open in addition to registering a service worker that listens for `push` events. But if you're putting in the effort to support the service worker use case, just relying on the service worker for all of your notifications might be cleaner.

One difference between the two approaches is that using the Notifications API while your web application is [supported in more browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API#Browser_compatibility) (as of August 2017) than service worker-based push notifications.

Comment: My requirement is to show the push notification even if the application is closed. So I am using service worker and I am getting the notifications that are pushed from the server. My problem is that, there are a set of notifications in my application which are being fetched from an external API. I want these notifications also to be pushed to client. So to get these set of notifications for all users can be tedious. So I tought, I will poll the external API from the service worker for new notifications and inform my server and then push those notifications from my server. Is this possible?

Comment: Inside of a service worker's `push` event handler, you can use `fetch` to make additional API calls and obtain detailed data about the specific notifications that you show. So the `push` could "wake up" the SW, and then the SW can use whatever logic you want to show notifications. The only restriction is that you should normally show *at least* one notification when you handle a `push` event, but https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/budget-api changes that a bit.